# How to Make scroll horizontal get the default div width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make scroll nav like youtube nav
I want to make the **scroll-horizontal** div get the width of the inline-block elemtns which is `<li>`
I want someway to make the **scroll-horizontal** div get the current width automatically even if I added more `<li>` elements to the nav later

```html
  <body>
    
    
        <nav>
          <div class="scroll-horizontal">
           <li class=" menu-item"><a class="active" href="">Home</a></li>
           <li class=" menu-item"><a href="">Models</a></li>
           <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Photos</a></li>
           <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Videos</a></li>
           <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Youtube</a></li>
           <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Links</a></li>
           </div>
        </nav>
    
    <style type="text/css">
    
    *{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0
    } 
     /*NAV*/
    nav{
        
        width: 100% !important;
        background: red;
        overflow: auto;
       
    }
    .scroll-horizontal{
       min-width: 300%;
    }
    nav li{
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        
    }
    nav a{
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #444;
        display: block;
        padding: 0 20px;
        width: 100px;
    }
    </style>
    
    </body>
```

the nav that youtube has:
[youtube nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcyQP.png)

you can see that the nav that they had don't have empty space at the end of the nav like what I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might partly answer your question:
As I understand it, the horizontal scroll arrows for the tab menu on youtube are shown, depending on the window width. So I would use the css '@media' rule to specify the width, when the arrows should be displayed. Here is a solution that displays both left and right arrows as soon as the window gets too narrow to display the complete menu:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body {
font-family: Arial;
background-color: #eee;
}

div.scrollmenu {
  padding: 0 38px 0 38px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #fff;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
}

#btn-scroll-lft {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 15px;
border: 0px;
height: 46px;
font-weight: bold;
display: none;
}

#btn-scroll-rgt {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 15px;
border: 0px;
height: 46px;
font-weight: bold;
display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #btn-scroll-lft {
    display: block;
  }
  #btn-scroll-rgt {
    display: block;
  }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<button id="btn-scroll-lft" onclick="scrollWinLeft()">&lt;</button>

<div class="scrollmenu" id="scrollmenu">
  <a href="#">one</a>
  <a href="#">two</a>
  <a href="#">three</a>
  <a href="#">four</a>
  <a href="#">five</a>
  <a href="#">six</a>
  <a href="#">seven</a>
  <a href="#">eight</a>
  <a href="#">nine</a>
</div>
<button id="btn-scroll-rgt" onclick="scrollWinRight()">&gt;</button>

<script>
function scrollWinLeft() {
  document.getElementById('scrollmenu').scrollBy(-100,0);
}

function scrollWinRight() {
  document.getElementById('scrollmenu').scrollBy(100, 0);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks Markus, you answered the question that I was need also you answered more than what I was need you teached me the property white-space: nowrap; I didn't now it before. I only used white-space: nowrap; and it worked.